# Any moderated group chat software?

Tags: chat, hosted, saas

I've just spent hours trying to find a simple hosted solution to add to my website for group text-based chat. I can't believe I couldn't find anything. I need to be able to moderate the chat, basically approving which messages get shown to everyone.

I tried, and payed for, [Chatwee](http://www.chatwee.com) the other day. Doesn't work, have written support many times. Got a response telling me it does work... Maybe they're a defunct business.

Similar situation with AddonChat.

Any others with the ability to approve messages from users before they get shown?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [JotCast](https://www.jotcast.com)?  It's a moderated chat software.  It sounds like what you're looking for, and they also have free accounts.